# how to push data in firebase using orderByValue in android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my code I push data using child considered as (ID), and every onfresh method it will update values (val1, val2, val3) using setvalue method. But while pushing data it stored data in ascending order referring to ID (every time ID is create as child, if child not exists, if is exist is will update the value). So I want store such type of data, when data is push then, data must be store in sequentially like `mdatarefrence.push()` method works.

```
mFireDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = mFireDatabase.getReference().child("Matches").child("Match_"+getmatch_id).child("commentry");


    mCommentryAdpter = new CommentryAdpter( getContext(),R.layout.commentrytuple, applications);

    commentry.setAdapter(mCommentryAdpter);

    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
{
    mCommentryEntry = dataSnapshot.getValue(CommentryEntry.class);
    mCommentryAdpter.add(mCommentryEntry);

     ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(commentry);

}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

}

@Override
public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

}

@Override
public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
```

Condition while pushing data

```
   mCommentryEntry = new CommentryEntry(va1,val2,val3);   
                         databaseReference.child(ID).setValue(mCommentryEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a push ID, call `push()` before calling `setValue()`:

```
mCommentryEntry = new CommentryEntry(va1,val2,val3);   
databaseReference.child(ID).push().setValue(mCommentryEntry);
```

Note that I'm not sure what `ID` is in your code snippet, so I just copied it here. If you want a unique, chronologically ordered, child key under `databaseReference`, you'd just call:

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(mCommentryEntry);
```

Comment: i respect your answer but how will i update key's which genrerated by firebase? please tell me if key is exist it will be update value else it is add to arrayadpter.

Comment: sir please give me your gmailid or whatsapp number i want to some need from you relation with realtime firebase. i am waiting for your replay... thank you

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works Shivam. But at this point it is also unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Here are the options for generating child nodes: 1) If you want to control the key used yourself, use `child(keyThatYouWant).setValue(...)`. 2) If you want Firebase to generate a unique, chronological key for you use `push().setValue(...)`.

Comment: thnkxx for reply but i am pushing value in firebase using option first , **child(keyThatYouWant).setValue(...)** but in this case , data stored in database in **ascending order reffering to (KeyThatYouWant).** means instead of (KeyThatYouWant) i use Unique (ID) and reffering to Unique (ID) data store in Acsending order , i want achive that data must be stored **chronologically ordered** but data stored in acsending order. sir please help me, i am waiting for your reply

Comment: If you want to determine your own keys, but still want to retrieve the nodes in chronological order, add a timestamp to each node, and then retrieve the nodes with `ref.orderByChild("timestamp")`.

Comment: how? please explain in detail with suitable example.. it's new for me... and thanxxx so much to supporting for me..